# this function tells me if I should go left or right in my binary tree and the compiler returns Error when trying to use the result with the & operator

Tags: c

these are the structures

```
typedef struct Node{
    int value;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
} TNode;

typedef TNode *TTree;
```

if I do this, the compiler returns error

```
TNode *is_left_or_right(TTree tree, int value){
    
    if (tree->value > value)
        return tree->left;
    else 
        return tree->right;
}

pointer = &(is_left_or_right(tree, value));
```

why the second statement works, meanwhile the first causes an error. If the & operator works on variables

```
TTree *is_left_or_right(TTree tree, int value){
    
    if (tree->value > value)
        return &tree->left;
    else 
        return &tree->right;
pointer = *is_left_or_right(tree, value);
```

The error: lvalue required as unary '&' operand

Comment: Do not hide pointers with typedef's, your code becomes very confusing.

Comment: The irony of using welcomed proper pointer types for your return result, `TNode *`, whilst simultaneously using a maligned pointer type hidden in a type alias for your root argument, `TTNode`, is ghastly. Do yourself a favor: don't hide pointer types in typedef aliases. Mantra: If its a pointer you want to see the splat.

Comment: Only variables have addresses.  You can't take the address of the result of a function call. You also don't need to do so. The function returns a pointer of the type you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why the second statement works, meanwhile the first causes an error. If the & operator works on variables

Because the `&` operator works on *variables*, and more generally on lvalue expressions, which designate objects, which have addresses.  It does not work on rvalue expressions, which represent values without (necessarily) any persistent storage or address -- for example, `12` or `x + 2`.  Function return values are rvalues.